# Implications of a Curve being Tangent to a Line

Tags: calculus, derivatives, proof-verification, tangent-line

In my experience, I have usually dealt with finding or analyzing tangents to a curve. In this question I've encountered, I am asked to analyze a curve given it is a tangent to the **line y=x**.

Here is the curve:

$y=(x^3/3)+ax+b. $

I am tasked to prove that the above conditions imply that:

$4(a-1)^3+9b^2=0$

I have deduced some things from the implication, but I feel that I have not deduced enough! Here is what I have understood so far:

The slope of $y=x$ is 1. At the point the curve is tangent to this line, it's slope is 1. Therefore, I differentiated the equation of the curve with respect to $x$ and reached the following conclusion:

$x^2+a=1$
so $x=\pm \sqrt(1-a) $

Substituting this result in the equation of the curve, I get

$y=((\pm \sqrt(1-a))^3/3)+a(\pm \sqrt(1-a))+b. $

This is something, but does not seem to get me closer to deducing the required.

At the point where the curve is tangent, we also have

$y=x=\pm \sqrt(1-a)=((\pm \sqrt(1-a))^3/3)+a(\pm \sqrt(1-a))+b. $

My question is thus:
Am I not considering an implication of the curve being a tangent to this line that will help me deduce the required?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose the point in question is at $x = p$. Then since the two curves intersect at this point and since the slope of their tangent lines are equal at this point, we have the system:
$$
\begin{cases}
p = \frac{1}{3}p^3 + ap + b \\
1 = p^2 + a
\end{cases}
\qquad\iff\qquad
\begin{cases}
-b = \frac{1}{3}p^3 + (a - 1)p \\
a - 1 = -p^2
\end{cases} 
$$
Substituting in the $(a - 1)$, we get:
$$
-b = \frac{1}{3}p^3 + (-p^2)p = \frac{-2}{3}p^3 \iff p = \sqrt[3]{\frac{3}{2}b}
$$
Substituting this back, we have:
$$
a - 1 = -\left( \sqrt[3]{\frac{3}{2}b} \right)^2 \iff (a - 1)^3 = -\frac{9}{4}b^2 \iff 4(a - 1)^3 + 9b^2 = 0
$$
as desired.

Comment: Thank you for displaying your method. I did not explicitly consider deducing a system of equations from the information we could deduce.